# How to check if my logo is a duplicate of another logo?

Tags: logo, resource-recommendations

As the title asks, how can I check to see if my logo is a duplicate of another logo?

Even though I didn't use another logo as a direct example to design my logo, I am worried that a logo similar to the one I made may already be used somewhere. Currently I am unaware of any way out whether or not that is the case. What are some ways to do so?

Comment: reverse Google image search?

Comment: https://www.tineye.com/ does something similar.

Comment: @DaveRose I edited your question to try and better state your current situation. Please feel free to edit it again to describe your questions better than I did!

Comment: As an aside, if you are worried about somebody eventually questioning if you logo was a copy of another, this is one of the many reasons to keep all of your sketches and draft work in archive. You could at this point at least support the position that the logo is an original work.

Comment: @Vincent: you _can_ actually upload an image into Google image search and search for similar images (or paste the URL if it's already online)

Comment: @PieBie that's what I thought :)

Answer (score 1):

By far the fastest and easiest way is to do a reverse image lookup in Google.
Here's a link to Google's Search by Image functionality:

http://www.google.ca/insidesearch/features/images/searchbyimage.html

Google will look for similar colours, shapes, and patterns in other images across the internet. Although it may find images that aren't logos at all, this is the quickest way to begin.

Past that, you can post in graphic design communities as Whitcomb suggests.
Here are some great communities that will give you the feedback you're looking for:

Brands of the World - http://www.brandsoftheworld.com/

Reddit Logo Forum - http://www.reddit.com/r/Logo_Critique/

Starting with Google and then transitioning into conversations with actual people, you should be able to cover your bases pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Try posting you logo in graphic design communities and getting feedback, chances are that if the logo is really similar, someone will notice.  As for "parameters" I don't know if you mean "how close your logo can be without being *copying*," but it's a good idea to stay away from similar logos simply for brand identity and originality's sake anyway.

Comment: The catch is, when posting a logo publicly for feedback, no matter what, you'll get 10 different "That looks a lot like the logo for X". So take it all with a grain of salt. :)